# Add access modifier to method using Roslyn CodeFixProvider?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I was at the TechEd a few days ago, and I saw [this talk by Kevin Pilch-Bisson (relevent part starts at about 18 minutes)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/DEV-B345) ... I thought is was pretty cool, so I decided to play around with Roslyn myself.

I'm trying to make a rule "Access Modifier Must Be Declared" (Stylecop SA1400) - meaning,

**This violates the rule:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
```

**This is ok:**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
```

It must have an explicit internal keyword, public keyword, private keyword, or protected keyword.

Detecting the violation was fairly easy, but now I'm trying to provide a fix. I've been trying things and searching everywhere, but I can't find out how to add access modifiers.

This is what I have so far:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CodeAction>> GetFixesAsync(Document document, TextSpan span, IEnumerable<Diagnostic> diagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var token = root.FindToken(span.Start);

    var methodDeclaration = token.Parent as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

    //var newModifiers = methodDeclaration.Modifiers.Add(SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));         
    //var newModifiers = new SyntaxTokenList() { new SyntaxToken() };

    MethodDeclarationSyntax newMethodDeclaration = methodDeclaration.WithModifiers(methodDeclaration.Modifiers);
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(methodDeclaration, newMethodDeclaration);
    var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

    return new[] { CodeAction.Create("Add Public Keyword", newDocument) };
}
```

The `WithModifiers` needs a `SyntaxTokenList`, which I can New(), but I don't know how to make it of `SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword`. I'm also not sure if I'm even suppose to new it, or use the `SyntaxFactory`. However, when using the `SyntaxFactory`, I also can't figure out which method I need to create a `SyntaxToken` of `SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword`

I can post the entire thing, including the `DiagnosticAnalyzer` if there's interest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I actually needed was this:

```cs
var newModifiers = SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(accessModifierToken))
    .AddRange(methodDeclaration.Modifiers);
```

It's almost what Chris Eelmaa suggested, but with that suggestion I ended up with `static public void Main` which is valid, but ugly.

Appending `public` adds it to the end of the list, and as far as I know, the access modifier should always be the first.

Comment: Looks good to me, except that you have an unused local "public TokenList".  Your Func will be called to create the preview as well as when clicked, but that should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks :) . Yea forgot the publicTokenList, usually resharper tells me about those, but since I was working in vs14 it didnt had that..

Answer (score 12):

Glad you enjoyed the talk!  We actually have some helpers in the syntax model to make it easier to add items to lists, so you should be able to do something like:

```
var newMethodDeclaration = methodDeclaration.AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));
```

To get the new method declaration.

The expanded form of this would be something like:

```
var newModifiers = SyntaxFactory.TokenList(modifiers.Concat(new[] { SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)}));
var newMethodDeclaration = methodDeclaration.WithModifiers(newModifiers);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did like the talk a lot! About the best talk I've seen at the teched, together with the Async one :) - Anyway, your suggestion kind of works, but I end up with `static public void Main`. I've added my own solution which seems to work. If would could review that in case I did something weird, that would be great though. Its the first thing I made for Roslyn, so there are probably a bunch of things to improve

Comment: Oh btw, why is the syntax of the AnalyzeNode this: `public void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNode node, SemanticModel semanticModel, Action<Diagnostic> addDiagnostic` and not this: `public Action<Diagnostic> AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNode node, SemanticModel semanticModel`? It seems a little strange

Comment: Because you can report multiple diagnostics. Also, having them be a callback lets us avoid some allocations, and to stream the results in as you report them asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to create modifiers that indicate `public static`, you can use this:

```
var modifiers = SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
    new SyntaxToken[] { 
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), 
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword) 
    }),
```

But in your case, I don't see why

```
var updatedModifiers = methodDeclaration
                .Modifiers
                .Add(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));

methodDeclaration.WithModifiers(updatedModifiers);
```

wouldn't work.

Comment: The first suggestion does not work because you obviously don't always need static, but I get its just to explain the syntax... Still, the second suggestion also does not really work, it results in `static public void Main` or static publicvoid Main

Comment: @RonSijm, +1. I have no problems if you clean up your answer & put only relevant stuff(eg get rid of `GetFixesAsync` and `CreateAction`)  & accept it. It's a good question.